# Playing sounds on Console - C#

Tags: c#, audio, console, console-application, soundplayer

I'm writing a Console application on C# and I want to play a sound when I display texts continuously. This is what I've done :

```
static SoundPlayer typewriter = new SoundPlayer("typewriter");
static public void print(string str, int delay)
    {
        Thread skipThread = new Thread(skipText);
        typewriter.PlayLooping();
        textgap = delay;
        foreach (char c in str)
        {
            Console.Write(c);
            if (textgap != 0)
                Thread.Sleep(textgap);

        }
        typewriter.Stop();

    }
```

`typewriter.wav` is imported to my project next to the `.cs` files and I've selected `copy always`. When I run this code, an error pops out when starting playing the sound saying `Please be sure a sound file exists at the specified location.`
What is wrong here?

EDIT :
Changed my code to the following according to Kevin J's answer.

```
static SoundPlayer typewritter;

    public static void Load()
    {
        Assembly assembly;
        assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        typewritter = new SoundPlayer(assembly.GetManifestResourceStream
            ("typewriter"));
    }
```

I also should precised to use the path `Environment.CurruntDirectory + "typewriter"` but nothing changes.

Comment: Does it put the file in the same folder as your executable?

Comment: @DStanley Yes, it does.

Comment: Unless you've imported the .wav file as a resource, you'll need to specify the exact path of your .wav file for SoundPlayer.  i.e. `SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer("C:\\bass.wav"))`.  Your code above doesn't appear to have a full path.

Comment: Looking at your new code, you are not putting the correct resource identifier for `assembly.GetManifestResourceStream`.  It should look something like "Yournamespace.typewriter.wav".  You only have "typewriter".  You MUST qualify the resource with the namespace of your app and the correct file name.  "typewriter" is not a correct name for a .wav file.

Comment: @KevinJ I can't put "mynamespace.typewriter.wav" as parameter to the function just because it says that typewriter is not defined.

Comment: Your code above is not showing the namespace.  Is your namespace actually called "mynamespace"?

Comment: @KevinJ It is not called "mynamespace", I just used that as an example. I put the actual namespace on my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured out the problem : I just needed to set the `SoundLocation` property of the `SoundPlayer` instance :

```
SoundPlayer typewriter = new SoundPlayer();
typewriter.SoundLocation = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/typewriter.wav";
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's something that might help you out (please note that this code is for a winforms app, but you should be able to convert to a console app.  Just study the code to see how it works)  You'll basically be adding the .wav file as a 'resource' to your program.  Then, your program can access the .wav file and play it:

[image]

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.IO;
using System.Resources;
using System.Media;
using System.Diagnostics;



namespace Yournamespace
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Assembly assembly;
            Stream soundStream;
            SoundPlayer sp;
            assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            sp = new SoundPlayer(assembly.GetManifestResourceStream
                ("Yournamespace.Dreamer.wav"));
            sp.Play();  
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, when I this, at least there are no errors but the sound played is just a system beep sound, nothing to do with my original sound.

Comment: Post your new code in your original question as an edit and let's see what you've got.

Comment: Editted my post according to your comments.

Answer (score 0):

If for example you have your sounds in the folder "Assets" then subfolder "SoundClips" do it like this.

```
var soundLocation = Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\Assets\SoundClips\";

SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer
{
    SoundLocation = soundLocation + "typewriter.wav",
};
```

Make sure you have the file properties set to:

build action  - Content

copy to output directory - Copy if newer