# How can I use OpenAL in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, openal

I'm trying to play a wav file from a .NET Core console application (No, I'm not using the console beep. Weird requirements, I know.). I figured I could do that using OpenAL. I'm able to read the file in fine, but then when I try to play it, it fails on the first line:

```
int handle = AL.GenBuffer();
```

I get the exception: `InvalidOperationException: Could not load openal32.dll`. I'm using the OpenTK.NETCore NuGet package. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. It turns out the OpenTK.NETCore package doesn't come with OpenAL, just the SDK. Instead, it looks for it already installed on the machine. I used [the installer](https://openal.org/downloads/), and imagine I'll need to install it on every machine that uses my application

Answer (score -1):

Not using OpenAL, but an alternative solution to play wav files in a console application can be found here:

[Playing sounds on Console - C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22028688/playing-sounds-on-console-c-sharp)

After adding the sound file to your solution the suggested code in the link is:

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.IO;
using System.Resources;
using System.Media;
using System.Diagnostics;



namespace Yournamespace
{
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Assembly assembly;
        Stream soundStream;
        SoundPlayer sp;
        assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        sp = new SoundPlayer(assembly.GetManifestResourceStream
            ("Yournamespace.Dreamer.wav"));
        sp.Play();  
    } 
}
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can use SoundPlayer from .NET Core.

Comment: OpenAl works cross platform, while your answer would only work on Windows, and won't work in  NetCore.