# How I can play audio in C# console application?

Tags: c#, audio

I would like to know if it possible just play some kind of audio file in C# Console Application.

I don't find any answer on this question.

Many Thanks

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using? What type of audio file are you trying to play (what is the extension? .wav? .mp3?) I'll try to help.

Comment: One more question. Where do you want this to run? On a Windows computer, mac, or linux?

Comment: I am trying to play MP3 on Windows computer. It should be just console application. Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with the proposed solution in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3502311/how-to-play-a-sound-in-C-net?

Comment: Because it's WPF, I amt talking about console app only.

Answer (score 0):

In command prompt you can play an audio file by typing it's name  from location folder:

```
c:\my_Music>track1.mp3
```

This opens the file with the format's *associated progam* so there will be a pop-up of an external program. Set program by using right-click on a file and choose "`Open With`".

I've not tested this in a console app. But you should be able to type a String into the console app and then trigger an `ENTER` press event.

**Option 2:**

Use [**SoundPlayer**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.media.soundplayer?view=netframework-4.8) class.
A [good tutorial](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/PlayingWavFiles.aspx) for beginners. 
Also can check this: [Playing sounds on Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22028688/playing-sounds-on-console-c-sharp).