# Sound Playback from console application in c#

Tags: c#, audio

Right now this is the code I have.
Apparently SoundPlayer doesnt exist in the namespace System.media

```
System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"c:\waterfall.wav");
   player.Play();
```

What else can i use? I mean theres tons of ways to do it in a window application but...

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/a/22030431/10708630

Comment: It should work just like that. Do you, by any chance, have a namespace System.Media that does not define SoundPlayer? Which version of .NET are you targeting?

Comment: Do pay attention to the project template you selected to get started.  For .NETCore and .NET 5.0 (aka ".NET") you need https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Windows.Extensions/

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the SoundLocation property before playing and it should work

```
var soundPlayer = new SoundPlayer();
soundPlayer.SoundLocation = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/waterfall.wav";
```